# Is there a way to pause/resume the SwingWorker

Tags: java, swingworker

Is there a way to pause/resume the [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) in Java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pause the task you run in the swing worker by implementing something like this

```
while(true) {
   if(paused)
   {
       try {
           Thread.sleep(500); // half a second
           continue;
       } catch(InterruptedException e)
       {
       }
   }
}
```

It is not very nice though.

Comment: you copied code from here http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t136961-pausing-a-swing-worker-thread.html but forgot to write loop :-)

Comment: Correct. Formatted it nicer though.

Comment: Don't do it this way.  Use wait() and notify() instead.